# Google Places API, only in US?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I am trying to develop an app in Android which can display information about places nearby but after several tries it seems the Google Places API can only shows information within US. It works good when the place is in US, I can get nearby shops,banks,restaurants,... But when I try with the place in VietNam, it tells nothing can be found.

However when I use the default Maps app in Android it does differently, I can find shops,banks,bus stations, ...

So is the API in the default Maps app in Android different than the Google Maps API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/) ?

Comment: Hiii IT-FAN currently I am working on the same kind of application where I need to find hospitals near by but I am getting ZERO_RESULTS as a response from the server.Can u provide any sample code for accessing google places API.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This call will find my favorite market in Saigon (were I always need to drink local coffee and have one of the best soups):

http://maps.google.com/maps?q=market&mrt=yp&sll=10.772265829894847,106.69806003570557&output=json

Doesn't this work for you?

Comment: The output file seems not to be really JSON. Check it here : http://json-indent.appspot.com/ How to handle it ?

Comment: I only needed speific data out of this. I never tried JSON on these results. I use Pattern/Matcher to pick stuff out of this.

Comment: I guess it would be slow to parse such kind of structure. Anyways, I will give it a try. Thanks !